# Error while installing pod in Apple Silicon (M1)

Tags: swift, ruby, cocoapods, apple-silicon

Command i am running is

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Warning: cocoapods 1.11.2_2 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.11.2_2, run:
brew reinstall cocoapods
~ % alias pod='arch -x86_64 pod'

Below is error :

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/conflict.rb:47:in `conflicting_dependencies': undefined method `request' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

    [@failed_dep.dependency, @activated.request.dependency]
                                       ^^^^^^^^
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb:61:in `conflicting_dependencies'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:193:in `exception'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:193:in `raise'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:193:in `rescue in resolve'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:191:in `resolve'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:411:in `resolve'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:423:in `resolve_current'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:230:in `finish_resolve'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:287:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `synchronize'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state': Unable to satisfy the following requirements: (Gem::Resolver::Molinillo::VersionConflict)

- `minitest (= 5.14.2)` required by `user-specified dependency`
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:682:in `attempt_to_activate'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:190:in `resolve'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:411:in `resolve'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:423:in `resolve_current'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:230:in `finish_resolve'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:287:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `synchronize'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

I Uninstall and install RUBY and COCOPODS again.
and now below is the error :

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:265:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) with executable pod (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:284:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It's possible you have two different Rubies installed, one via Home Brew, and the one Apple installs for their own use in `/Library/Ruby`. Try `which ruby` from the terminal. I recommend _NOT_ using Brew for a development environment, instead I use rbenv, but YMMV.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I solved this by removing cocoapod and installing it again

```
gem cleanup
brew uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
sudo gem install cocoapods-user-defined-build-types
pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue while setting up react native cli on mac M1
solution which worked for me

```
gem cleanup
brew uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
sudo gem install cocoapods-user-defined-build-types
```

then check the pod version by running

> pod --version

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your yarn.lock or package.lock file. hopefully, that works.

if that doesn't work, try `rvm install ruby-3.1.1` `rvm --default use ruby-3.1.1`

Comment: worked for me, installing ruby using rvm and then making it default use. it will change version as well path.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue when *running* `pod install`, NOT during the installation of Cocoapods. [This](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4968#issuecomment-991225632) GitHub comment helped me solve it. I was using ruby 3.0.0. I installed 3.0.3, followed by Cocoapods, and then `pod install` started working.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error. I'm using rvm (RubyVersionManager). Make sure that you're using the same version of Ruby as when you first ran the install. If you're running the install for the first time, make sure that you're not using the system version of Ruby (It's a very old version).

In my case, I was trying to run pod install on version 3.0.0, but I should've been running it on 3.1.2, changing my version fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

**Cocoa-pods Install in M1**

I use HomeBrew https://brew.sh/

Here how its works.

**Copy & Run this command in terminal**

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

If you get any warning like(Warning: /opt/homebrew/bin is not in your PATH.
Instructions on how to configure your shell for Homebrew
can be found in the 'Next steps' section below.)
then please ignore these two commands.

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/shourob.datta/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

**Now Install Cocoapods**

```
brew install cocoapods
```

**Now Install pods, locate the project**

```
Pod install
```

**DONE**